# Populating my tableview with parsed json in a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Very new to iOS, a bit lost on what to do. I actually HAVE all that I need, I just need help putting said information into my tableview now. I am debugging and everything is correct when I hover over the variables in my "init" function, but when I go down to the function that handles the cells something is just not clicking. Very frustrating having the information you need but don't know how to put it where you want.

I hate coming to SO for these kind of questions but I have exhausted all other options. Before posting on here, I have tried everything. I tried to google other projects that I can reference, did not find any that was iOS 7 or relevant to my project. I apologize for this elementary question, and thank you in advance.

MasterViewController.m

```
@interface MasterViewController () {
    __block NSString * jsonString;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize coursesController = _coursesController;
-(void)getJSONString
{
    jsonString = [JSONHelper JSONgetString:@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True"];
}

-(void)initCourses
{
    [_coursesController.masterCoursesList
        removeLastObject];

    NSError *coursesError = nil;

    NSArray *coursesNameList =
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers

                                      error: &
     coursesError];
    if(coursesError)
        NSLog(@"[%@ %@] JSON error: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]),
              NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), coursesError.localizedDescription);

    NSArray *coursesNames = [coursesNameList objectAtIndex:0];
   for (NSString *courseName in coursesNameList) {
        NSString *stringToUse = [courseName substringFromIndex:8];

       //initialize variables
       NSString *name = courseName;
        NSInteger *courseid = 00;
        NSString *imageUrl = nil;

        //add current building to list
        [_coursesController masterCoursesListWithName:name AndcourseID:courseid AndimageURL:imageUrl];

    }


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CoursesCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    Courses *courseAtIndex = [self.coursesController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:courseAtIndex.courseName];

    return cell;
}
```

CoursesDataController.m

```
@interface CoursesDataController()
-(void)initializeDefaultDataList;
@end

@implementation CoursesDataController
@synthesize masterCoursesList = _masterCoursesList;

-(void)initializeDefaultDataList
{
    NSMutableArray *coursesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Courses *course = [[Courses
                        alloc]initWithName:@"Loading Now..." AndcourseID:00];
    [coursesList addObject:course];
}

-(void)setMasterCoursesList:(NSMutableArray *)newCourseList
{
    if(_masterCoursesList != newCourseList)
    {
        _masterCoursesList = [newCourseList mutableCopy];
    }
} //this function is created when you create a NSMutableArray MasterCoursesList

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self initializeDefaultDataList];

        return self;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(NSUInteger) countOfList
{
    return [self.masterCoursesList count];
}

-(Courses *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSInteger)theIndex
{
    return [self.masterCoursesList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}

-(void)masterCoursesListWithName:(NSString *)cName
      AndcourseID:(NSInteger *)cID
      AndimageURL:(NSString *)cURL
{
    Courses *courses;
    courses = [[Courses alloc] initWithName:cName
                                AndcourseID:cID
                                AndimageURL:cURL];
    [self.masterCoursesList addObject:courses];
}

-(void)courseName:(NSString *)cName
      AndcourseID:(NSInteger *)cID
{
    Courses *courses;
    courses = [[Courses alloc] initWithName:cName AndcourseID:cID];
    [self.masterCoursesList addObject:courses];
}



@end
```

CoursesDataController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Courses;

@interface CoursesDataController : NSObject


@property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *
masterCoursesList;
-(NSUInteger) countOfList;
-(Courses *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSInteger)theIndex;
- (void)masterCoursesListWithName:(NSString *)cName
                AndcourseID:(NSInteger *)cID
                AndimageURL:(NSString *)cURL;

- (void)courseName:(NSString *)cName
       AndcourseID:(NSInteger *)cID;


@end
```

JSONHelper.m

```
+(NSString *)JSONgetString:(NSString *)query
{

    NSString* searchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:query];

    NSError* error = nil;               //error for NSUSRLConnection
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:searchURL];
    [request setURL:URL];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];

    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error performing request %@", searchURL);
        return 0;
    }

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonString:%@", jsonString);
    return jsonString;
}
```

I have a lot of code posted, however there are only a few lines that really matter for my question. When I hover over "name" in the following line of code        `[_coursesController masterCoursesListWithName:name AndcourseID:courseid AndimageURL:imageUrl];`
I get what I need (it loops through each JSON array and displays each one). But in the function that handles my cells, when I hover over courseName it doesn't say anything.

```
Courses *courseAtIndex = [self.coursesController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[cell textLabel] setText:courseAtIndex.courseName];
```

EDITS:

numberOfRowsInSection function in MasterViewController.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.coursesController countOfList];
}
```

Comment: (how my professor taught us) we use the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath function to update cells. I've seen it work before as well, but with hardcoded stuff. in my [[cell textlabel] setText:courseAtIndex.courseName] is how I am attempting to reload the data.

Comment: Yes, but after that model changes you need the line [self.tableView reloadData]; to actually call that method again and update the table

Comment: Can you please show the implementation of `objectInListAtIndex:` and `masterCoursesListWithName:` in `CoursesDataController`?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr they are shown... Scroll down in that window.

Comment: @PCoder123 I looked at an example my professor gave me and I don't see anywhere where he does that, but his works. I would simply just reference his except the JSON he parses comes from a JSONObject, and I have a JSONArray parsed. I am not saying you are wrong by any means, but I just don't think that's my issue. Do you think that it is though? If so I will look up some info on what to do for that, just want to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: One thing I JUST noticed is when I put a break point in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function, it never hits it??

Comment: You have your data source and delegate set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

in **CoursesDataController.m**

```
-(void)initializeDefaultDataList
{
    self.masterCoursesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Courses *course = [[Courses
                        alloc]initWithName:@"Loading Now..." AndcourseID:00];
    [self.masterCoursesList addObject:course];
}
```

Comment: Tried this with no results. I do appreciate you taking the time to help though, so I thank you for that.

Comment: Where you initialising `CoursesDataController` in `MasterViewController` and also please share `numberOfRowsInSection:` code.

Comment: If im not mistaken I am initializing the CourseDataController here : "    [_coursesController.masterCoursesList
        removeLastObject];" Will post that code in edit in OP. Thank you.

Comment: Try init CourseDataController by `_coursesController = [[CourseDataController alloc] init]` and use the above code.